# How to detect a custom key from Keyboard using C#

Tags: c#

I have a USB Keyboard that have some Special keys like "FN",PLAY,MUTE and one that changes the keyboard light. I was trying to get what is this key "name" to perform a logic to change the color periodically.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var key = sender as TextBox;

        var result = key.Text;
    }
```

But the key its not a string to be recognized. How can I do this ? Thanks!

Comment: Here is a list of Virtual Key Codes: (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx) This may help you in accomplishing your goal.

Comment: Have you considered handling the KeyDown event rather than the TextChanged event?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use `OnKeyPress` and `OnKeyDown` events instead to check what was pressed. [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeypress(v=vs.110).aspx).
Example:

```
// Boolean flag used to determine when a character other than a number is entered.
private bool nonNumberEntered = false;

// Handle the KeyDown event to determine the type of character entered into the control.
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Initialize the flag to false.
    nonNumberEntered = false;

    // Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the top of the keyboard.
    if (e.KeyCode < Keys.D0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.D9)
    {
        // Determine whether the keystroke is a number from the keypad.
        if (e.KeyCode < Keys.NumPad0 || e.KeyCode > Keys.NumPad9)
        {
            // Determine whether the keystroke is a backspace.
            if(e.KeyCode != Keys.Back)
            {
                // A non-numerical keystroke was pressed.
                // Set the flag to true and evaluate in KeyPress event.
                nonNumberEntered = true;
            }
        }
    }
    //If shift key was pressed, it's not a number.
    if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift) {
        nonNumberEntered = true;
    }
}

// This event occurs after the KeyDown event and can be used to prevent
// characters from entering the control.
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // Check for the flag being set in the KeyDown event.
    if (nonNumberEntered == true)
    {
        // Stop the character from being entered into the control since it is non-numerical.
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it didn't detect my key, only the CTRL key

Comment: @NathielBarros The event has not been triggered ?

Comment: Nope. Only with the normal keys

Comment: @NathielBarros If the event is not being triggered then the only way to find out how the key press can be captured is to find the dev. guide for your keyboard or it's specifications document containing the way how it works. That special keys can process functions instead of triggering key press event for example